# How can I create a confusion matrix and determine the effect of a 50% cuttoff in R?

Tags: r, confusion-matrix

I have the values of a certain confusion matrix I want to analyze and determine the effect a cuttoff will have. Lets say I have these vectors:

```
v1 <- c(200, 25)
v2 <- c(10, 400)
```

these are the values of a confusion matrix (transposed,  row 1 would be (10, 200), row 2 would be (400, 25). I want to know how a 50% cuttoff would affect the false negative.

Comment: with a confusion matrix, you have already assigned the labels. you need to start with the probabilities, see the answer by Ben

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do this with just a confusion matrix. The cutoff is used to create a confusion matrix. You need to have the data the confusion matrix is made from to assess the effects of different cutoffs. Here is an example. Let's say we have some data like the following:

```
data <- structure(list(response = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                    1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
                       y = c(4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 
                             4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4), 
                       z = c(4, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 2, 2, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 
                             4, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 2, 1, 2, 2, 4, 6, 8, 2)), 
                  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -32L))

head(data)
  response y z
1        1 4 4
2        1 4 4
3        1 4 1
4        0 3 1
5        0 3 2
6        0 3 1
```

Let's say we fit a model to predict `response` based on  `y` and `z`.

```
mod <- glm(response ~ y + z, data = data, family = "binomial")
```

Now we can predict the values of `response` and add them to the data.

```
data$fit <- predict(mod, type = "response")
head(data)
  response y z          fit
1        1 4 4 4.217892e-01
2        1 4 4 4.217892e-01
3        1 4 1 8.435784e-01
4        0 3 1 2.345578e-09
5        0 3 2 1.204047e-09
6        0 3 1 2.345578e-09
```

Our `fit` values are not useful, because they are continuous, and the `response` is binary. So, we choose a cutoff, say `0.5` (or 50%). When we do this, we lose information. We know whether `predicted` is above or below the cutoff, but we lose the original value.

```
data$predicted <- (data$fit >= 0.5) ^ 1 # TRUE ^ 1 = 1, FALSE ^ 1 = 0

  response y z          fit predicted
1        1 4 4 4.217892e-01         0
2        1 4 4 4.217892e-01         0
3        1 4 1 8.435784e-01         1
4        0 3 1 2.345578e-09         0
5        0 3 2 1.204047e-09         0
6        0 3 1 2.345578e-09         0
```

The `caret` package has a function to generate a confusion matrix.

```
library(caret)
confusionMatrix(factor(data$predicted), factor(data$response), positive = "1")$table

          Reference
Prediction  0  1
         0 17  2
         1  2 11
# 2 false negatives, false negative rate = 15.3%
```

We cannot recreate the original data from this confusion matrix. If you want to choose a different cutoff, you will to go back to the original data. Then you will get a new confusion matrix.

```
# cutoff = 0.25
data$predicted2 <- (data$fit >= 0.25) ^ 1 # TRUE ^ 1 = 1, FALSE ^ 1 = 0
confusionMatrix(factor(data$predicted2), factor(data$response), positive = "1")$table

          Reference
Prediction  0  1
         0 15  0
         1  4 13
# 0 false negatives, false negative rate = 0%
```

Comment: Thanks alot for really making this clear; I appreciate the thorough explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You already seem to have the confusion matrix. If you want additional statistics on it, you can use `caret` package. Just create a matrix and make it's class `table`.

```
m = cbind(v2, v1)
dimnames(m) = list(G1 = c("A", "B"), G2 = c("A", "B"))
attr(m, "class") = "table"
CM = caret::confusionMatrix(m)
CM
```

As for the effect of different cutoffs, the other answer provides more information.